# Transfer file from ftp to S3 via io.Pipe

Tags: go, aws-sdk

My go code

```golang
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
    "github.com/secsy/goftp"
)

func main() {
    clientConfig := goftp.Config{
        User:               "myUser",
        Password:           "myPassword",
        ConnectionsPerHost: 10,
        Timeout:            10 * time.Second,
        Logger:             os.Stderr,
    }

    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-east-1")},
    )

    uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(sess)

    client, err := goftp.DialConfig(clientConfig, "myFeed.wmyDomain.com:myPort")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    reader, writer := io.Pipe()

    client.Retrieve("myPath/myFile.gz", writer)

    result, err := uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
        Body:   reader,
        Bucket: aws.String("myBucket"),
        Key:    aws.String("myTestFile"),
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Failed to upload", err)
    }

    log.Println("Successfully uploaded to", result.Location)
    writer.CloseWithError(err)
}
```

This is my output

```golang
  goftp: 0.000 #1 opening control connection to [myIP]:myPort
    goftp: 0.134 #1 sending command USER myUser
    goftp: 0.203 #1 got 331-Username ok, send password.
    goftp: 0.203 #1 sending command PASS ******
    goftp: 0.269 #1 got 230-Login successful.
    goftp: 0.269 #1 sending command FEAT
    goftp: 0.336 #1 got 211-Features supported:
     EPRT
     EPSV
     MDTM
     MFMT
     MLST type*;perm*;size*;modify*;unique*;unix.mode;unix.uid;unix.gid;
     REST STREAM
     SIZE
     TVFS
     UTF8
    End FEAT.
    goftp: 0.336 #1 sending command TYPE I
    goftp: 0.403 #1 got 200-Type set to: Binary.
    goftp: 0.403 #1 sending command SIZE myPath/myFile.gz
    goftp: 0.474 #1 got 213-33620711002
    goftp: 0.474 #1 was ready
    goftp: 0.474 #1 was ready
    goftp: 0.474 #1 sending command TYPE I
    goftp: 0.544 #1 got 200-Type set to: Binary.
    goftp: 0.544 #1 sending command EPSV
    goftp: 0.610 #1 got 229-Entering extended passive mode (|||60706|).
    goftp: 0.610 #1 opening data connection to [myIP]:myOtherPort
    goftp: 0.677 #1 sending command RETR myPath/myFile.gz
    goftp: 0.746 #1 got 125-Data connection already open. Transfer starting.
```

However, it seems to just get stuck there and doesn't do anything.  The file is large but I have 0 movement on network activity whatsoever.

I'm able to download the file when using os.Open or os.Create and pointing my client to retrieve into that stream but not when using S3.  It doesn't even attempt to download the file then.

UPDATE:
Thanks to @Peters suggestion of using multiple go routines, I did manage to get this to work.  However I ran into an issue with defer statements as I understand they're supposed to run towards the end of the function call or go routine.  This is my new code.

```golang
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
    "github.com/secsy/goftp"
)

func main() {

    // Use sync to force each goroutine thread to complete
    messages := make(chan int)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // Start a session with aws us-east-1 region
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-east-1")},
    )

    // Create a client for s3
    uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(sess)

    // Create a client for goftp
    // TODO Have credentials pulled from SSM
    client, err := goftp.DialConfig(goftp.Config{
        User:               "MyUser",
        Password:           "MyPassword",
        ConnectionsPerHost: 10,
        Timeout:            10 * time.Second,
        Logger:             os.Stderr,
    }, "myftpHost.com")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Instatiate IO stream
    reader, writer := io.Pipe()

    // Set number of goroutines to wait for
    wg.Add(2)

    // goroutine thread that pulls the file from ftp and puts it in writer stream
    go func() {
        defer writer.Close()
        defer client.Close()
        err = client.Retrieve("MyFiletxt", writer)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        wg.Done()

        messages <- 1
    }()

    // goroutine thread that pull from reader thread and pushes it to s3
    go func() {
        defer reader.Close()
        result, err := uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
            Body:   reader,
            Bucket: aws.String("MyBucket"),
            Key:    aws.String("myTestFile"),
        })

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln("Failed to upload", err)
        }

        log.Println("Successfully uploaded to", result.Location)

        wg.Done()
        messages <- 2
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

The issue is that the defer statements would never run causing the io to constantly run and the entire script to be in a stuck state.  Not sure why the defer statements aren't doing their job.

Comment: Retrieve blocks, waiting for someone to read from the read end of the pipe. That doesn't happen until after Retrieve is done, so you have a deadlock. Retrieve and Upload have to be executed in different goroutines.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for that explanation.  Given that this file is very large, I don't want to really download it or store it in memory, can you think of any other way to stream the file over to S3?

Comment: io.Pipe doesn't store anything in memory: "The data is copied directly from the Write to the corresponding Read (or Reads); there is no internal buffering." Your code does what you want, you just have to run the reading and writing parts concurrently.

Comment: @Peter, your solution of multiple go routines worked.  However, I ran into another issue with defer, which I'll update my question with.

Comment: The send on messages blocks because the channel is unbuffered and nothing receives from messages.